# I am unable to get MS Visual Studio Express 2013 to create a ".exe"

Tags: visual-studio-2013, masm

So I am taking an Assembly Language class.  I am using MS Visual Studio Express 2013.  The first couple programs I had to do went well because the Professor started them, zipped them up, and kicked it to us to finish.  Now, however, we are starting from scratch.  I have created the .asm that is required, and written the program.  When I build it I have a couple of problems.

1) he is requiring comments on what we are doing (duh) but I am getting the "red squiggly line" underneath them (looks like a misspelling in MS Word) these are returning as intellisense errors "expected a ..." type stuff after each ";" which is the proper way to comment in assembly.

2) my biggest problem is that I cannot get VS to populate a .exe that will actually run the damn thing.  I can build it (with the intelliesense errors) and even compile it.  But the .exe never generates.

I have submitted my code to my professor and it is written correctly, but he does not know why I cant get the thing to work properly.

I have established all the settings according to the books instructions.  I have pored through countless web sites.  I have uninstalled and reinstalled VS.  I even tried installing VS 2012 as that is what my instructor is using, but windows 8 wants me to disable compatibility mode to do this... which I cant seem to figure out either.

Does anyone have ANY idea on what I can do?  Or even a different compiler I could use to create MASM programs?  I found Notepad++ but I can only write the .asm, not compile and run... or create that damned .exe I need.

Comment: is the name of the assembly file "`somthing.ASM`" ?  ("ASM" can be lower case)

Comment: Masm32 (http://www.masm32.com/).

Comment: yes, the project and the file both carry the name of the assignment... but the assembly file is a ".asm"... not a .cpp or anything like that.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, if you right-click on the project (the project, not the solution) in the solution explorer and choose 'Build Customizations', is masm listed?  And checked?

Answer (score 0):

I have found what appears to be a very useful document on Kip Irvine's web site, **Getting Started with MASM and Visual Studio 2013** at http://www.kipirvine.com/asm/gettingStartedVS2013/index.htm#CreatingProject. This process works on Visual Studio 2013 Express. As a proof of concept, I used the suggested method to build the following program with VS 2013 Express.

```
.386
.model flat,c
.stack 1024

.data
msg     db "Hello World!",0

.code
includelib MSVCRT
extrn printf:near
extrn exit:near

public main
main proc
    push offset msg
    call printf
    push 0
    call exit
main endp

end main
```

As I already mentioned in an earlier comment, MASM32, found at http://www.masm32.com/, is another option. If you decide to go with MASM32, you may also want to consider using WinAsm Studio found at http://www.winasm.net/.

One benefit of MASM32 is that it comes with INC files (MASM version of header files) that have been generated for you and add on libraries. One downside of MASM32 is that it only supports 32-bit development.

If you want to build 64-bit applications you should use Visual Studio 2013. Note that the above code will not build as a 64-bit application.

Comment: Actually we are using Irvine's book in the course so I have followed these steps.  Thanks for suggesting an alternate program but these do need to be 64-bit applications.  I have followed and re-followed the tutorial on Irvine web site but keep hitting the same issue.

Comment: Just curious... What is the latest version of MASM64?

Comment: I have no idea why you are having problems. As I said, I was able to build the program. I also ran it and it worked correctly. One note. The executable is found in the directory $(SolutionDir)\$(Configuration). The object files are found in a different directory.

Comment: One note. The executable is found in the directory $(SolutionDir)\$(Configuration). The object files are found in a different directory. When I created the project the solution file was placed in "%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\MASMTest." This is the $(SolutionDir). The project file and code was placed in "$(SolutionDir)\MASMTest." The object files were placed in "$(SolutionDir)\MASMTest\Debug." The exe was placed in "$(SolutionDir)\Debug." Maybe you are just looking in the wrong place.